# Django not sending emails to local

Tags: python, django, email, django-views

I am very new to django and previously had emails sending to my terminal using:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

I am trying to access the PasswordResetConfirmView template but cannot access the url as it is not appearing in my terminal. I believe it is now not sending an email.

Here is what I used before in my settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Here are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Homepage
path('', views.home, name='home'),
# Login/Logout
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
# Register
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
# Profile
path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
# Edit profile
path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
# Edit password
path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
# Password reset
path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html'),
     name='reset_password'),
path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name= 'accounts/reset_password_done.html'),
     name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name= 'accounts/reset_password_complete.html'),
     name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

And a change_password view:

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user= request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect(reverse('view_profile'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('change_password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user= request.user)
    args = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)
```

I am not sure why this has stopped sending emails and I am getting no errors on any page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use class base views to handle password reset and attach this to your settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

Note: That you don't need the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT since you are sending it to the terminal.